# What would be the Iterator equivalent for this for each loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Someone knows the Iterator equivalent?

```
for (Type a : list) {
    for (Type b : a) {

    }
}
```

My Approach is

```
for (Iterator<Type> it1 = a.iterator(); it1.hasNext();){
  for (Iterator<Type> it2 = b(a).iterator(); it2.hasNext();) {

  }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `b(a)` supposed to be? What exactly "doesn't work"? Please put some effort into your question

Comment: You need to call it1.next(); it2.next();

Comment: So your `Type` is `Iterable`?

Comment: "it doesnt work" isn't a working problem description. Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. And hint: why use iterators when you have that nice for loop construct?

Comment: Seems to be a tree structure, as the inner-most `Type` objects are `Iterable` too and so again provide more `Type` objects by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing missing calls to `Iterator`'s `next()` method, which are required to advance the iterators and obtain the current value.

```
for (Iterator<Type> it1 = list.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
  Type a = it1.next();
  for (Iterator<Type> it2 = a.iterator(); it2.hasNext();) {
      Type b = it2.next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's [right there in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

...and then shows this example:

> ```
> List<? extends Integer> l = ...
> for (float i : l) ...
> ```
>
> will be translated to:
>
> ```
> for (Iterator<Integer> #i = l.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     float #i0 = (Integer)#i.next();
>     ...
> ```

So your version is mostly fine, except:

1. You're trying to call `a.iterator` to start, but your enhanced `for` example shows `a` as the outer loop variable; it should be `list` to start with.
2. You need to call `next`
3. You need to use the outer loop variable (`a`) when getting the inner loop iterator

*(You don't need the casts that they give in the example; they needed them for completeness, but you're just using `Type` where they were using `float` to loop through an `Integer` list.)*

So:

```
for (Iterator<Type> it1 = list.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
// -----------------------^^^^
  Type a = it1.next();   // <==
  for (Iterator<Type> it2 = a.iterator(); it2.hasNext();) {
// -------------------------^
    Type b = it2.next(); // <==
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Type a : list){
  for(Type b : a){
    // Do something with b
  }
}
```

to

```
for(Iterator<Type> itList = list.iterator(); itList.hasNext();){
  Type a = itList.next();
  for (Iterator<Type> itA = a.iterator(); itA.hasNext();){
    Type b = itA.next();
    // Do something with b
  }
}
```

`.next()` is used to get the value in the iterator-iteration. So in your initial code the `b(a)` should have been `it2.next()` (and the `a` and `b` should have been `list` and `a`).

Also, `Type` should be Iterable itself, otherwise the initial nested for-leach loops wouldn't have worked to begin with. The following would have made more sense if `Type` is just a DTO-object:

```
for(List<Type> a : list){  // `list` is of type List<List<Type>> in this case
  for(Type b : a){
    // Do something with b
  }
}
```

In which case the `Iterator<Type> itList` should have been `Iterator<List<Type>> itList` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<Type> itA = list.iterator();

while(itA.hasNext()) {
    Iterator<Type> itB = itA.next().iterator();

    while(itB.hasNext()) {
        Type b = itB.next();
        // TODO payload
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (Iterator<List<Type>> it1 = a.iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
            for (Iterator<Type> it2 = it1.next().iterator(); it2.hasNext();)
               Type b=it2.next();

        }
```

Comment: It would make the answer much better in the long run if you could add an explanation why this works while the asker's code doesn't (even though the codes appear very similar).

Comment: @Dev-iL thanks for your suggestion . I will  definitely try to explain more from next time . Its different from the askers's code is in the second for loop the asker does use the first iterarator next() while my code do .